# Scaling Node.js App on Heroku Using Dynos

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory-management, scaling, dyno

I am trying to better understand scaling a Node.js server on Heroku. I have an app that handles large amounts of data and have been running into some memory issues.

If a Node.js server is upgraded to a 2x dyno, does this mean that automatically my application will be able to handle up to 1.024 GB of RAM on a single thread? My understanding is that a single Node thread has memory limit of ~1.5 GB, which is above the limit of a 2x dyno.

Now, let's say that I upgrade to a performance-M dyno (2.5 GB of memory), would I need to use clustering to fully take advantage of the 2.5 GB of memory?

Also, if a single request is made to my Node.js app for a large amount of data, which while being processed exceeds the amount of memory allocated to that cluster, will the process then use some of the memory allocated to another cluster or will it just throw an error?